# On click confirmation always deletes

Tags: javascript, php

In a php file, I have the following code:

```
echo '<form action="../apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="check" />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$ID.'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="confirmDelete()" "style="margin-right: 5px;" />';
echo '</form>';
```

The function:

```
function confirmDelete()
{
    var agree= confirm("are you sure?");
    if (agree == true)
        {
        return ('<?php  
            if (isset($_POST['check']))
            {
                if ($queryType == "apps")
                {
                    $deletePath = "delete/";
                    include $deletePath.'deleteApp.php';
                }
            }
            ?>');
        return true;
        }
    else
        {
        alert("you pressed cancel");
        return false;}
}
```

The alert box shows up when cancel is pressed, but instead of canceling the action, it deletes it anyway. I am new to javascript and am not sure what is wrong.

Pressing the OK button deletes everything correctly, but the calcel button immediately deletes the app as well.

Comment: Your `return true` is never reached.

Comment: PHP is a server side scripting language. You can't use it inside javascript! You want to do an ajax request and run a php script with it!

Comment: @Fred What? He is defining a javascript function `confirmDelete`. He then tries to execute PHP with javascript. This is not possible! Even syntax highlighting fails - this code can never be valid!

Comment: @fred: the code's useless, though. two `return` statements in a row, mixing JS and PHP. Pointless string concatenations... basically it's a fine example of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: @DennisFischer I retracted my previous comments and to be honest, I took it for granted that the OP's code was valid, without actually testing it myself. This falls into the classic **"Fool me once, shame on you. Fool me twice, shame on ME"**. (I rarely do the same mistake twice). You were right and I was wrong. Please accept my sincere apologies, cheers.

Comment: @MarcB You were also right. I won't and hope not to fall into a trap like that again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result in the onclick attribute.

```
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirmDelete()" "style="margin-right: 5px;" />';
```

---

**ps:** you don't have to echo huge strings of HTML. You could easily replace all of those `echo` calls with this

```
<form action="../apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"">
  <input type="hidden" name="check" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID ?>" />
  <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return confirmDelete()" />
</form>
```

Comment: @user2572833, if this code worked for you, please click the checkbox next to his answer.